# How to call cms block of block type into custom header

Tags: magento-1, phtml, header, cms-block

I've made code of most viewed products which I'm trying to call under custom header. This is what I've done so far.

Posted the block code under cms block by name 'most_viewed'.

```
{{block type="mostviewed/list" name="home.mostviewed.list" alias="product_homepage" template="catalog/product/mostviewed.phtml"}}
```

and then I've posted the below code under my custom header but it's showing block. Suggest me some good idea to do.

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('most_viewed')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Comment: in which pages custom header has been called?

Comment: Only on home page

Comment: where you call {{block type="mostviewed/list" name="home.mostviewed.list" alias="product_homepage" template="catalog/product/mostviewed.phtml"}} code at  admin

Comment: Already said above that I've called that under cms-block

Comment: Without {{block type="mostviewed/list" name="home.mostviewed.list" alias="product_homepage" template="catalog/product/mostviewed.phtml"}}  code, Have you add  any thing  else in ] cms blocks

Comment: No I've not added anything apart from the block type code

Comment: Sorry about this but, can't add a comment yet. Quoting you here: > Well, I followed this tutorial magikcommerce.com/blog/… and make block, however I'm unable to call it on custom header. Is it possible to directly copy paste the codes under app/design/frontend/default/YourTheme/template/catalog/product/mostviewed.phtml into the header but calling some public classes? I have come to a conclusion that when working with magento layout files and nothing seems to be working the way it should, cache is almost certainly the culprit. Just to be sure, when you followed [this](http://www.magikcommerce.c

Answer (score 0):

According to discussion with you.you need to do this by using layout xml

**Home handler:** `cms_index_index` is `unique` for homepage.

`Suppose` that the name of `custom header` is `customheader`

then you can define the most_viewed by

```
<cms_index_index>
<reference name="customheader">
<block type="mostviewed/list" name="home.mostviewed.list" as="product_homepage" template="catalog/product/mostviewed.phtml" />
</reference>
</cms_index_index>
```

Then you need call this block by using `getChildHtml(BlockNameATXmlCOde)`

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_homepage');?>
```

Please put this code at cms.xml or local.xml at `app/design/frontend/YOUR_PAcakage/YOUR_TEMPLATE/layout/`

**If you using layout code then no need to cms block**

Hi you need to change reference name custom header

```
<reference name="header"> <block type="page/header" name="customerheader"> <action method="setTemplate"><template>cms/home.phtml</template></action> </block></reference>
```

Then  accordingly you need to change most view block reference block name

```
<cms_index_index>
<reference name="customerheader"> <!-- here parentblock name which is define at above xml -->
<block type="mostviewed/list" name="home.mostviewed.list" as="product_homepage" template="catalog/product/mostviewed.phtml" />
</reference>
</cms_index_index>
```

Comment: not working though

Comment: please tell me ?name of custom header at layout xml code ? Just block type="mostviewed/list" name="home.mostviewed.list" as="product_homepage" template="catalog/product/mostviewed.phtml" name is name="home.mostviewed.list"  and aliase name is product_homepage

Comment: Well I've simply put the <reference name="header">
    <block type="page/header" name="header">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>cms/home.phtml</template></action> 
    </block> in Home LAYOUT DESIGN
</reference>

Comment: just change reference name="customheader" to reference name="header".Also i have using alias name in childblock call

Comment: Well I do have changed that to header and posted  and also I've called with alias name but still not working.

Comment: Well, I followed this tutorial http://www.magikcommerce.com/blog/how-to-show-most-viewed-best-selling-products-in-magento-store/ and make block, however I'm unable to call it on custom header. Is it possible to directly copy paste the codes under app/design/frontend/default/YourTheme/template/catalog/product/mostviewed.phtml  into the header but calling some public classes?